# Does KML support a search function

Tags: kml, google-earth

Is there a KML tag sequence which will position Google Earth to the specified location?

If I start Google Earth, type "Houston" in the search text box and press [Search], the map is positioned to Houston, Texas.

Can you accomplish this via KML?

If not, how would you go about doing this?  I'm attempting to do this from a C# application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic KML files look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Name of KML</name>
    <StyleMap>
    .........
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder>
    ......
    </Folder>
</Document>
```

If you assign a `<LookAt>` or `<Camera>` to the `<Document>` node, whenever the KML is loaded it should load that view - unless told otherwise (eg via API/COM)

So your KML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Name of KML</name>
    <LookAt>
    ..........
    </LookAt>
    <StyleMap>
    .........
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder>
    ......
    </Folder>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to center on a single point / feature among many in a KML file?

There is (to my knowledge) no way to define initial map settings via KML. That said, Google Earth 5.0 supports Tours, and using a FlyTo element would accomplish this goal of centering on a location, but I don't believe there is anyway to auto-play a playlist without JavaScript or a plugin (which your requirement for doing this in the KML seems to negate).

I know that the Google Maps API auto-centers and zooms on a loaded KML file (can anyone comment on if Google Earth does the same?). I haven't tried, but I am curious if there is a way to take advantage of this behaviour using folders. If (and a big if):

1. Google Earth centers/zooms on a loaded KML file, and
2. Google Earth does this on only data in the first or last folder

(Neither of which I know to be true)

You could try putting your search point in a folder to itself and seeing if the map tracks to it.

I apologize that the entire second part of this response is a wild guess, but I cannot test it out right now and thought it might be worth a try. If I were betting on it my answer would be that it can't be accomplished with KML alone. It is pretty easy to test the hack above and if you don't get a chance I should have time later tonight to try it out and post an addendum.

Comment: I'm developing a .NET Windows Forms app in C#, and what I'm actually trying to do is allow the user to type a location in a search box that I can pass to GoogleEarth in some manner.  I have EARTHLib referenced and I instantiate an ApplicationGE object which contains a read-only SearchController reference, however, if I retrieve the SearchController reference and attempt to use it via its Search() method, COM errors are thrown.

Comment: I am guessing my version of GE (v7) deprecated this functionality, since Google has made an obvious effort to move away from the COM API.

I hoped I could use KML. I attempted to get and use the GoogleEarth Browser plug-in through a .NET WebBrowser object. This is extremely weird, IMO, and why this is the "preferred" API doesn't make much sense to me, but opinions aside, I haven't been able to get that API to work at all. Probably a mental disconnect on my end. Anyways, the bottom line is I can't seem to embed Google Earth in a frame and invoke any sort of search functionality.

Comment: The alternative is to allow GoogleEarth to launch itself as a separate application and let the user search via GE's side panel. This works okay, but it distributes the UI across two separate forms, which I am trying to avoid.

Hope this makes sense...